# How Can I Get Stats Showing in Google Search Results Meta Description?

Tags: seo

I'm wondering how it's possible to get Google to show stats below the meta description like in the image below.  I've scanned the source code of the site for any sign of structured data and didn't see anything.  I also put the site in Google's "Structured Data Testing Tool", and it didn't find anything either.

The only thing I see is an HTML table in the source code that contains this information.  Given, from what I understand, tables are best used sparingly these days, I guess I'd find it surprising that Google would provide a benefit to such a structure.

[image]

Comment: It would help to know what domain name appears in your image along with the search query you used. Tables have historically been used for data presentation and was the first target of the knowledge graph for seeking and parsing data. Tables have their place. If you do this, be sure to use table headers and what-nots. Otherwise, it may not work.

Comment: It looks like tabular data: numbers associated with a data label.   Seems like an appropriate use of tables to me.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the feedback guys.  I'm going to try and setup data on my page in a table format similar to that which I saw on the other site.  Have either of you ever seen this type of meta data in search results before?  I've been trying to find other examples and this is the only site I can find.